What do philosophic schools or individual philosophers say about gaining knowledge despite our transience
Why should someone seek out and acquire knowledge when they'll inevitably leave this world? Their consciousness won't exist and the knowledge they stored will be gone.
I get that knowledge is necessary to deal with some situations. But many people have a thirst for knowledge all the way to their end, when they won't even know they had it. Wouldn't it be meaningless to work for something you'd lose anyway?
What are some philosophical justifications for the pursuit of knowledge in a temporary existence?.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Things are not worthless if they may lose their value at a later point
of time.
Knowledge has a value for our life, because devoid of knowledge life
becomes impossible.

From a philosophical viewpoint one can question whether life  per se
has a value. But in general living beings have an intrinsic will to
live.



I'd question your first point. Arguably, everything is at least ultimately worthless, and merely temporally valuable.

@ConnieMnemonic I agree with you concerning "temporally valuable".

It would be lost to 'you', but there would be a record. People strive for legacy, to leave a record or a mark, and scholars tend to try and do that in the domain of knowledge.
We don't aquire or create all our knowledge, we inherit most of it, and take it in through education. If we get to the point of doing research, we help work on the body of knowledge, and leave some trace on what future people will inherit. We are stewards of it. Of course eventually all the stars will go out, and any traces evaporate.
So even in the absence of concern for contributing to the knowledge of others who follow, I argue that curiosity is one of the best motivations in life for us to cultivate, in this answer:
If everything ends one day why don't we end it today?
We can think of play, and the creation of new language games and modes of life that develop from it, as the deeper paradigm for how to live when we are free from scarcity and suffering. Discussed here: Meaning of life, given all my problems have been solved
Camus said

"Man stands face to face with the irrational. He feels within him his longing for happiness and for reason. The absurd is born of this confrontation between these human needs and
the unreasonable silence of the world."
-in The Myth of Sisyphus

If the world is accepted as absurd, there is no one answer to how to live a meaningful or good life. Some choose knowledge. Some wealth, or power. Or creative practices. One day every trace will be gone, yet still right now there is a little time we must fill. As Camus concludes, the struggle for our absurd goals must in the end be enough to fill our hearts, if we choose to believe that. And if not, well then, it can't have mattered..

"Is it possible that existence is our exile and nothingness our home?”
-Emil M. Cioran


"And if the Wine you drink, the Lip you press,
End in the Nothing all Things end in -- Yes --
Then fancy while Thou art,  Thou art but what
Thou shalt be -- Nothing -- Thou shalt not be less."
-quatrain 47 from the Rubaiyat of Omar Khayyam


N.B.: this answer says nothing about whether "having meaning" equals "good" - or "not having meaning" means "bad". Some of the comments go in that direction, but that is a very different question as far as I'm concerned.

Why should one acquire knowledge, have a thirst for knowledge

Who said that this is the case?
As far as I'm concerned:

This kind of thirst is not something you do for ethical reasons, it is simply a property of our brains - so more a topic for neuroscience ("how?") or maybe evolutionary psychology ("why?").
From personal experience, not everybody has a drive to acquire knowledge, nor a thirst for it, at the very least not at every stage of their lives – this might change over time for each person. And those people are not morally "bad" for not being interested.


when they'll leave this world and their consciousness?

Yes, everything eventually ends. This is not a special phenomenon regarding accumulation of knowledge. In this special case this means that any ethical reason for acquiring knowledge will be based on what you eventually do with it before you die; or that you accept that it's just the way our brain machines work.

how do people just want knowledge all the way to their end

Psychology. Quite obviously, knowledge is power. If you know which berries are poisonous, and how to hunt difficult prey, and who in the village is likely to deceive you, this is incredibly useful. So at a basic level, we can think that there is an evolutionary benefit (higher fitness, higher chance of survival, easier to get your offspring through a hard winter...) when you know more.
Hence, our animal brains probably have a mechanism which creates this thirst - on a similar autonomous level as other basic "features" of our brains, like striving for warmth, food, and so on and forth.
From experience, the actual physical act of gaining knowledge can be extremely and immediately fulfilling. Recall times when you were actually interested in some topic, went out to study it, and finally learned what you wanted to know. These "heureka" moments are likely giving us a nice little dopamine kick.
This would explain why many people like to know more, all the time. Even if in modern days this maybe regresses to "junk" knowledge that never gives you any tangible benefit at all. It is unlikely that evolution would have somehow guarded us against too much knowledge, as having that has only been a thing in the very recent past. Until some hundred years ago, it was certainly possible for a polymath who had all basic needs covered, and a long productive life, to acquire a large percentage of the overall knowledge of humanity; and in prehistoric times, where evolution still played a major role, there certainly was very little to know, compared to today, easily within the capacity of our brains.

Wouldn't it be meaningless to work for something you'd lose anyway?

"Meaning" is not easy to come by. This depends largely on your worldview - i.e., what you mean by meaning. But yes, if you have no mystical thing that gives you meaning (i.e., religion, gods etc.) and if you don't do something great with your knowledge (e.g. use it to increase net happiness around you), then accumulating knowledge would just be a meaningless hobby like playing sports or chess - in the very least it would make you happier, and more "fit" for the world (i.e., you'd have an easier time to apply your knowledge if and when you eventually do need it), but aside from that it would be meaningless.

If you're not searching for knowledge and understanding, the best that could be said about you is that you're "not harmful". But you might as well be, intentionally or not.

Imho excelling in sports or chess is, in that sense, very meaningful and a search for knowledge. You learn about yourself and others, cooperation and fair competition, adjacent crafts (repair boats, grow a green lawn, ..), enable others to do the same, ... . Ok, you can sit on your hometrainer for an hour four times a week, that's a sport too. ;)

Feel free to create your own answer, @Karl - I'm happy to agree to disagree.

Camus summed up his entire philosophy:

There is only one really serious philosophical problem and that is suicide. Deciding whether or not life is worth living is to answer the fundamental question in philosophy.

In the same vein, his contemporary Frenchman Sartre:

It is absurd to be born; it is absurd to die

Or Kierkegaard

To be a human being is to be in a state of despair. The greater the knowledge, the greater the despair, for with knowledge comes the awareness of the paradox of existence.

But my favorite is the lyrical beauty of the Book of Ecclesiastes from the Bible/Torah. You may rejoice that you are following in the way of the wisest of the wise — King Solomon
(Emphasis added to highlight the connection with your question)

The words of the Preacher, the son of David, king in Jerusalem.
Vanity of vanities, saith the Preacher, vanity of vanities; all is vanity.
What profit hath a man of all his labour which he taketh under the sun?
One generation passeth away, and another generation cometh: but the earth abideth for ever.
The sun also ariseth, and the sun goeth down, and hasteth to his place where he arose.
The wind goeth toward the south, and turneth about unto the north; it whirleth about continually, and the wind returneth again according to his circuits.
All the rivers run into the sea; yet the sea is not full; unto the place from whence the rivers come, thither they return again.
All things are full of labour; man cannot utter it: the eye is not satisfied with seeing, nor the ear filled with hearing.
The thing that hath been, it is that which shall be; and that which is done is that which shall be done: and there is no new thing under the sun.
Is there any thing whereof it may be said, See, this is new? it hath been already of old time, which was before us.
There is no remembrance of former things; neither shall there be any remembrance of things that are to come with those that shall come after.
I the Preacher was king over Israel in Jerusalem.
And I gave my heart to seek and search out by wisdom concerning all things that are done under heaven: this sore travail hath God given to the sons of man to be exercised therewith.
I have seen all the works that are done under the sun; and, behold, all is vanity and vexation of spirit.
That which is crooked cannot be made straight: and that which is wanting cannot be numbered.
I communed with mine own heart, saying, Lo, I am come to great estate, and have gotten more wisdom than all they that have been before me in Jerusalem: yea, my heart had great experience of wisdom and knowledge.
And I gave my heart to know wisdom, and to know madness and folly: I perceived that this also is vexation of spirit.
For in much wisdom is much grief: and he that increaseth knowledge increaseth sorrow.

It can be found in other cultures and systems as well:

The unlettered are more easily saved than those who are learned merely with the mind but not subdued. They are free from the clutches of the demon of pride; they are free from the malady of many whirling thoughts and words; they are free from the mad pursuit of wealth; they are free from many ills.


There will come a time when a man will have to unlearn all he has learned
Ramana Maharshi

The points made by Solomon and Ramana are unpleasant. And
there is a natural tendency to rebel at them.
But they are inexorable because we assume

Reality = Physical reality — Physicalism
Knowledge arises exclusively from physical(ist) experience — Empiricism

The alternatives are many and varied — idealism, theism, spirituality or simply religion.
I prefer to call it dualism — there is physical reality, and there is another realm.
Once this assumption is allowed it becomes possible to posit

the knowledge of our sensible realm is perishable knowledge
the knowledge of the other realm is at least possibly imperishable.


The knowledge at which geometry aims is the knowledge of the eternal
Plato

[Note the "aims"!]
Finally note that death and the process of dying can be faced in an unbelievably cheerful and meaningful way without any reference to a spiritual realm – here is Emily Levine.

I can give you my take on it. Influenced a little bit by Camus. If you are already born on this world and you "have" to live it (if you exclude the option of suicide), than I think that it is better to spend your time by enjoying life and for some people learning is one of the greatest joys there is.
Also you can connect your question with this question. Why learn anything if in the end we know that we will never know everything? There is no absolute truth. It is all a game that we choose to accept to play.
Here is a quote to sum up:

I'm filled with a desire for clarity and meaning within a world and condition that offers neither. ~Albert Camus,The Myth of Sisyphus



the knowledge they stored will be gone anyway

That is incorrect.  If you manage to publish a significant book, music, art, technology, journal article, software, etc. your knowledge will not be gone.  Other than those artifacts, if the knowledge you store is considered valuable by others,

they will archive it in a library somewhere (such as the C.S. Lewis Archives at Wheaton College's Marion E. Wade Center Repository), or
collect it in boxes to be passed down to your next generation
become a subject of a biography, or at least
exist in other artifacts in the company / school / organization / government you once worked for.

I heard heroes of ancient Greeks are not afraid to die of being forgotten because they consider themselves to live eternally in the celebration of the people they defended.  Or at least if your impact is positive to your descendants, your impact continues to live through them when they remember "grandma used to say this", or "I live this way because I admire how grandpa do ....", etc.
Millions of people will live purposeful enough that through their lives they will leave the world a better place than before they were born.  If sufficient number of people benefited from the departed's life and the knowledge he/she acquired, the knowledge will not go to waste.  Lots of people write diaries and letters to their descendants, if not also publish memoirs for public consumption, which will be kept if valuable.
